# How do you fill a form AND trigger change event using Python?

Tags: python, forms, dom, beautifulsoup

I have a web form that I'm trying to fill out using Python.  This is not a form that a submit button is pressed.  It is a dynamic form that is updated on change events.  I'd had this setup with a *.user.js script at one time using Greasemonkey and jQuery.  I had to fill the field, then manually trigger the change event so that the server actually updated the database with the entered value.  This script is no longer accessible to view.

Now I'm trying to do a very similar task, but using Python.  I can access the site, parse the data using BeautifulSoup, and select the element that needs to be modified.  But I'm struggling to understand whether interacting with the elements within the BeautifulSoup object actually mimicks the use of a web browser, or just the text stored in the object.  Finally, assuming that it is, in fact, the same as interacting with a website, how do I trigger the change event to have the site update it's database?

Example of the HTML element parsed:

```
<td class="cell text-center hidden-text cell-by-class " data-an="13"  data-sn="14830" data-status="" data-transfer-value="">
<span class="score-value text-uppercase"></span>
<div class="score-info "></div>
</td>
```

Working code that pulls the above element (and others like it):

```
...{working code}....
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_from_request.text,'lxml')
elements = soup.select('td[data-an="13"]')
```

print(elements) yields a list of elements, including the TD element from above.  I need to enter some value within the  tags...shouldn't be a problem.  But when I enter a text value there, how do I trigger the change event so that it acts like I modified the value in a browser window, which would trigger the updating of that value within the server's database?

I hope I described that clear enough.

Comment: You can't. BS isn't a browser driver, just an HTML parser. You need something like Selenium

Comment: Thank you.  Looking into that now.

Comment: @pedwards you don't use BeautifulSoup to fill forms. You can use the requests module, specifically requests.post , watch few videos, look around for that how to post data to a website using requests. Shouldn't take more than 10min of learning, peace!

Comment: I've used requests to fill forms that are submitted via some <form action...  But can it be used to enter a value on a form that is "submitted" on a change event?  I'm sure it's an AJAX method triggered on change().